# C# - How To Convert Object To IntPtr And Back?

Tags: c#, winapi, callback, marshalling, intptr

I want to pass an object from managed code to a WinApi function as `IntPtr`. It will pass this object back to my callback function in managed code as `IntPtr`. It's not a structure, it's an instance of a class.

**How do I convert `object` to `IntPtr` and back ?**

Comment: Pin it using GCHandle

Answer (score 63, accepted):

So if I want to pass a list to my callback function through WinApi I use [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx)

```
// object to IntPtr (before calling WinApi):
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
GCHandle handle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(list1);
IntPtr parameter = (IntPtr) handle1;
// call WinAPi and pass the parameter here
// then free the handle when not needed:
handle1.Free();

// back to object (in callback function):
GCHandle handle2 = (GCHandle) parameter;
List<string> list2 = (handle2.Target as List<string>);
list2.Add("hello world");
```

Thx to [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, you need to free the handle after use. Also I used casting. It might be wise to use the static methods `GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle1)` and `GCHandle.FromIntPtr(parameter)` like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). I haven't verified that.

Comment: `handle1.Free();` must move to last line, otherwise will throw the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 17):

While the accepted answer is correct, I wanted to add a little bit to it.

I have grown fond of creating extensions for this so it reads: `list1.ToIntPtr()`.

```
public static class ObjectHandleExtensions
{
    public static IntPtr ToIntPtr(this object target)
    {
        return GCHandle.Alloc(target).ToIntPtr();
    }

    public static GCHandle ToGcHandle(this object target)
    {
        return GCHandle.Alloc(target);
    }

    public static IntPtr ToIntPtr(this GCHandle target)
    {
        return GCHandle.ToIntPtr(target);
    }
}
```

Also, depending on how much of this you're doing, it might be nice to contain your list in an `IDisposable`.

```
public class GCHandleProvider : IDisposable
{
    public GCHandleProvider(object target)
    {
        Handle = target.ToGcHandle();
    }

    public IntPtr Pointer => Handle.ToIntPtr();

    public GCHandle Handle { get; }

    private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
    {
        if (Handle.IsAllocated) Handle.Free();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~GCHandleProvider()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
    }
}
```

And then you might consume it like this:

```
using (var handleProvider = new GCHandleProvider(myList))
{
    var b = EnumChildWindows(hwndParent, CallBack, handleProvider.Pointer);
}
```