# How to pass this pointer as context parameter for callback in c#

Tags: c#, interop

In **C++** it's common to pass the 'this' pointer to a callback registration method so that the callback will receive this pointer back.  I have a 3rd party library that i am trying to interop with from **C#** that uses this pattern.

Ex.

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI PFNCALLBACK*)(CALLBACKDATA *data, void *context);

HRESULT SetCallback (PFNCALLBACK *callback, void *context);
```

I've defined a delegate for the callback function:

```
public delegate int Callback(IntPtr context, CallbackData sample);
```

and call the `SetCallback` function

```
void SetupCallback()
{
  // My stab at passing the this pointer as context for the callback
  IntPtr pThis = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(this));
  hr = obj.SetCallback(OnCallback, pThis);
}

public static int OnCallback(CallbackData data, IntPtr context)
{
   // HOW do I reconstitute the This pointer from the context parameter
}
```

My question is how do I pass a **C#** 'this' pointer to the `SetCallback` method and reconstitute it in the callback function?

Comment: `OnCallback` is an instance method. What's wrong with the `this` reference it's already got?

Comment: Fixed.   OnCallback is static because it is not passed the implicit 'this' pointer.

Comment: Makes sense. Wouldn't expect a C function to be able to invoke a .NET delegate properly when all it's expecting is a pointer to a C function with whatever calling convention.

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340419/424129

Comment: That seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, you are asking for an interop nightmare, especially since you are dealing with a "black box" third party DLL.

Having said that, theoretically this should be possible by utilizing the 
UnmanagedFunctionPointer attribute.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate int Callback(IntPtr context, CallbackData sample);
```

Then store off your delegate

```
static Callback _someCallBack = null;
_someCallBack += new Callback(OnCallback);
```

Finally pass in the delegate when calling the C code

```
IntPtr pThis = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(this));
hr = obj.SetCallback(_someCallBack, pThis);
```

I also don't think you even really need to mess with the *this* pointer, unless you really need it in the callback honestly I would try passing in null. It's not safe in .Net land to marshall and marshall references back and re-use it.

Comment: Actually,  I am dealing with a black box .lib file for which I created a dll that wraps it.   The .lib has a function that creates an unregistered COM object.  The COM object has an interface with the callback registraton method.